# What is the best way to create a clock controlled by circular gesture with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, clock

I'm trying to create a circular clock with flutter, where each of the time buttons () will be controlled separately (the user will previously inform how many time buttons he will need, 1, 2, 3, etc). Each of these buttons needs to return the respective scheduled time.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlOXv.jpg)

Is it possible to do that? Could you help me understand what would be the best way to start this creation? What widgets could I use? I'm out of ideas and don't know where to start.
Many thanks!

Comment: look at this [https://docs.flutter.dev/clock](https://docs.flutter.dev/clock)

Comment: thanks but that didn't help.